# Can't access METHODS AND PROPERTIES with marcaube/ObHighchartsBundle

Tags: php, symfony, highcharts

I have problem to implement this function into my hightcharts chart:

```
function callback() {
    this.renderer.path(['M', -8, 0, 'L', 8, 0, 'M', 0, -8, 'L', 8, 0, 0, 8])            
}
```

I create the chart like this:

```
$ob = new Highchart();
$ob->chart->renderTo('currentIrradiationChartContainer');
$ob->chart->type('solidgauge');
$ob->chart->marginTop(50);
```

and so on. But now I don't know how to implement this function. I try

```
$ob->renderer->path(['M', -8, 0, 'L', 8, 0, 'M', 0, -8, 'L', 8, 0, 0, 8]);
```

But it do not work... Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the result?

Comment: Method renderer does not exist. Is not the correct way to implement this function. I suppose there is some other way to implement this? I want to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-activity/#run